# Ruby sequel equivalent to ActiveRecord none

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm looking for a way to replicate the behavior of [`none`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/none) in Sequel. So far I haven't been able to find a way to create a dataset, or a dataset like thing, without tying it to a table.

At the moment I am just returning an `enum` but I would like to preserve the dataset API to not break any chaining.

E.g.

```
class User < Sequel::Model
end

User.none  # => instance of dataset
```

Comment: You could use something like Rspec::Instance Double to create a mock object, and use it in production instead of for testing. Probably pretty expensive way to go about it.

Comment: Interesting! Yeah, i'd rather not `require` Rspec in production if possible.

Comment: Maybe a dumb idea, but still, have you tried to use `Sequel::Dataset.new` for that purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequel has a null_dataset extension for this: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/null_dataset_rb.html

Comment: Perfect! I'll try to submit a PR adding some mention of this to the `active_record` section of the sequel docs. My google-fu may have been weak, but I tried searching for a bit to no avail.

Comment: I'm finding the usage of this to be pretty awkward. I need to say `DB[:users].nullify` instead of `User.nullify` or `User.dataset.nullify`. I'd like to avoid grabbing the database itself to return a null dataset. This might be helpful clarification for the body of your answer, or I can ask a separate question.

Comment: Assuming you ran `DB.extension :null_dataset` before creating the User class, then you should just need to do `def User.nullify; dataset.nullify end`